# Writable atomic property cannot pair synthesized setter/getter

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

I have the following Dog.h and Dog.m and getting the error in the title. How can I change the code to get this to work?? Would really appreciate some insight!

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Dog : NSObject

@property int age;


-(void) setAge: (int) value;
-(int) returnAge;

@end



 #import "Dog.h"

@implementation Dog

@synthesize age;


-(void) setAge: (int) value
{
    age = value;
}

-(int) returnAge
{
    return age;
}

@end
```

Comment: change the property to  @property (nonatomic,assign) int age;

Comment: and remove @synthesize age;

Comment: You can `@synthesize` and `(assign)` is unnecessary. Also you have defined the getter method wrongly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Dog : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int age;

@end



 #import "Dog.h"

@implementation Dog

@synthesize age = _age;


- (void)setAge:(int)age
{
    _age = age;
}

- (int)age
{
    return _age;
}

@end
```

The `_age` variable should only be used in the getter and setter methods. If you access the variable elsewhere in the .m file you should use `age` or `self.age`. And from outside the .m file you should use `dog.age`.